# Tracking multiple objects with merging,dividing of objects in scenes in point clouds

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, kalman-filter, particle-filter

I have a stream of RGBD images. After removing plane surface, I am performing Euclidean clustering on each of them to give me the centroids of the objects present in the scene for each frame. But the label associated with which of these objects keeps changing with each frame.

Essentially, I need to track objects (where merging and dividing of objects can take place) and designate them a consistent label. I have the X,Y,Z of the objects for each frame. I wanted to know of any mathematical models that can do this task? I am not able to find an example of a tracker in PCL also. But since I have already extracted the centroids of the point clouds it might be possible for me to code this up from scratch in MATLAB/Python.

These are two objects present in scene.

> X_1,Y_1,Z_1
>
> X_2,Y_2,Z_2

Say object 2 now divides into two. I want to keep track that these new objects have originated from object 2. In the next frame, the object coordinates will be something like this

> X_1,Y_1,Z_1
>
> X_2_1,Y_2_1,Z_2_1
>
> X_2_2,Y_2_2,Z_2_2

Comment: Just a quick suggestion: Can I suggest a "particle filter"? You can also check out the "multiple hypothesis tracker".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I am finding it difficult to incorporate merge/divide of objects while using the particle filter. I'll check out the MHT thing.

Comment: With the particle filter "model selection" isn't done explicitly, it is true and would need some tricks. Computer vision guys have to deal with this kind of thing a lot. See for e.g. "Using Spatio-Temporal Continuity Constraints to Enhance Visual Tracking of Moving Objects", a paper that I found enjoyable. Also see JPDAF.